# Recurring Event of Google calendar

Tags: laravel

How i can add recurring rule in google calendar in laravel.
I am using below given library, for creating google calendar link.

"https://github.com/spatie/calendar-links" .

Here i am sharing my code for google calendar recurring event please suggest me with adequate solution, it is working .
very fine for creating link for single event but it is not creating recurring event.

```
  "$timeStamp = strtotime(str_replace('/','-','Sat 24/12/2018 5:56 PM'));
    $dateTime=date('Y-m-d H:i',$timeStamp);
    $from = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i',$dateTime);
    $from = $from->format('Ymd\THis');
    $endDate=date('Y-m-d',$timeStamp);
    $newEndDate = $endDate." 24:00";
    $to = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i',$newEndDate);
    $to = $to->format('Ymd\THis');
    $url = 'https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE';
    $url .= '&text=Event_Test';
    $url .= '&dates='.$from.'/'.$to;
    $url .= '&rrule=FREQ=WEEKLY;DTSTART=20181231T000000Z;INTERVAL=1;COUNT=1';
    $url .= '&details='.urlencode('Event_Test');
    $url .= '&location='.urlencode('Delhi');
    $url .= '&sprop=&sprop=name:';
    return $url;"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this. I cloned the repository and then added the following to the Event.php. This allows me to pass in the parent eventId and get a collection of just the instances.

```
public static function instances($eventId, string $calendarId = null, string $max_results) : Collection
{
  $googleCalendar = static::getGoogleCalendar($calendarId);
  $googleEvents = $googleCalendar->getInstances($eventId, $max_results);
  $useUserOrder = isset($queryParameters['orderBy']);
  return collect($googleEvents)
    ->map(function (Google_Service_Calendar_Event $event) use ($calendarId) {
        return static::createFromGoogleCalendarEvent($event, $calendarId);
    })
    ->sortBy(function (Event $event, $index) use ($useUserOrder) {
        if ($useUserOrder) {
            return $index;
        }

        return $event->sortDate;
    })
    ->values();
}
```

Also needed to the the following to GoogleCalendar.php

```
public function getInstances(string $eventId, string $max_results): array
{
  return $this->calendarService->events->instances($this->calendarId, $eventId, array('maxResults' => $max_results))->items;
}
```

Now to get the child instances of a recurring parent event use:

```
Event::instances($schedule->google_event_id,$schedule->location->calendar_id, '5');
```

Note that my project has a Locations table with Schedules that tie together locations and tasks, so each location has it's own google calendar and the google event id is stored in the schedules table.